# Strange spontaneous run crash

Tags: c++, debugging, crash

I'm getting some strange errors and crashes from my project atm.

It started out with crashes where I got this message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
```

So I started adding some **cerr << "1"** etc to try and find at what line it crashed.

Now I've found the crash-line, allthough it doesn't print out the same error code. In fact, it doesn't say anything, just crash.

The line that causes the crash is this:

```
Item* tempItem = new Item(name, id2, desc);
```

Item.h constructor looks like this:

```
Item(std::string name_, int itemId_, std::string description_ = "") 
: name(name_), itemId(itemId_), description(description_){}
```

and the variables I'm sending in looks like this:

```
string name = "Frying pan";
int id2 = 1;
string desc = "It's all rusty";
```

any ideas? (If you need more code just tell me what you need and I'll edit it in)

**EDIT**
some updated info:

```
name.max_size() = 1073741820
name.length() = 9

desc.max_size() = 1073741820
desc.length() = 14
```

**EDIT2**
I've now tried creating the Item-objects with hard coding the variable values right before construction as such:

```
name = "itemName";
desc = "itemDesc";
id2 = 2;
```

and it STILL crashes right at the line:

```
Item* tempItem = new Item(name, id2, desc);
```

Comment: Wouldn't a debugger be easier than sprinkling `cerr` messages throughout the code?

Comment: any chance you pass negative length to string constructor?

Comment: if you try to create a string t("something", -1); you can get same exception

Comment: This is a pretty standard red flag for heap corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit on how long a `std::string` may be. `std::length_error` is thrown when that length is exceeded. The actual limit depends on your compiler's implementation of the Standard Template Library.

From the C++ standard (19.2.4):

> The class `length_error` defines the type of objects thrown as
>   exceptions to report an attempt to produce an object whose length
>   exceeds its maximum allowable size.

You can check the maximum allowable string size by reading the value of `string::max_size`.

Comment: well yeah, But I'm not getting that error any longer. besides, shouldn't "It's all rusty" be within the limits anyways? its not like it's a long string.